# Loading data to datagridview from excel gives error

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcombobox

I am trying to upload records to my `datagridview` from excel. My `datagridview` contains a `combobox` column which is populated with account numbers.

All fields till the comboxbox are loaded correctly. When the load reaches the combobox it throws an error "Combobox value is invalid" . When I say only to the error , it continues the load without any issues.
I cannot change the `combobox` value after the load as it throws the same error ,even if I hover over the field.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround for this.
Loaded from excel into a table in sqlserver and the datasource of the datagridview was set to this table.
It worked fine.